# Why setFromMatrix() position doesn't work?

Tags: three.js, react-three-fiber

I'm working with 3D objects, and suddenly have this issue. I am saving my scene in the server so that when I refresh my the webpage the objects inside the scene will not disappear, but the problem is the objects inside the scene aren't in the right position, they always go in the (0, 0, 0) position, which, I think, shouldn't happen because I already set its position before render, but I don't know if I'm doing it the right way.

```
const ObjectBuilder = (props) => {
    const { geometry, object } = props;
    const objRef = useRef();

    const matrix = new THREE.Matrix4();
    const loader = new THREE.BufferGeometryLoader();
    const position = new THREE.Vector3();
    const parsedGeom = loader.parse( geometry );

    matrix.set(...object.matrix);

    position.setFromMatrixPosition( matrix );

    const handleClick = (e) => {
        e.stopPropagation();

        props.click({ data: objRef });
    }

    console.log('matrix', matrix); //elements: [0, 0, 1111, 0, 50, 0, 0, 0, 0, 50, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
    console.log('position:', position); // x: 0, y:0, z:0

    return(
        <mesh
            name="map_object"
            ref={objRef}
            onClick={handleClick}
            receiveShadow
            castShadow
            scale={50}
            geometry={parsedGeom}
            position={position}
            matrix={matrix}
        >   
            <meshStandardMaterial
                color="white"
                metalness={0.3}
                roughness={0.5}
            />  
        </mesh>
    );
}
```

Thank you guys so much in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> console.log('matrix', matrix); //elements: [0, 0, 1111, 0, 50, 0, 0, 0, 0, 50, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]

This looks wrong. Your comment shows only 15 array elements although the `elements` property should hold 16.

Assuming `object` is an instance of `THREE.Object3D` the following line is incorrect, too.

```js
matrix.set(...object.matrix);
```

You can't use the spread operator with an instance of `THREE.Matrix4`.

Comment: Sir @Mugen87 , the object that I have declared above is actually the data of the 3d object that I'm fetching from my server, and I must have missed an element from the `console.log('matrix: ', matrix)`, because when I checked it, it shows this `matrix: elements(16)`. Is there any option that I can use to load my 3d objects in their right positions? Btw, thank you for your answer.

Comment: Have you considered to load your JSON via [ObjectLoader](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html?q=objec#api/en/loaders/ObjectLoader)? To do so, you have to serialize your objects or scene via the respective [Object3D.toJSON()](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html?q=object3d#api/en/core/Object3D.toJSON) method.

Comment: I'll try that. Anyway, I'm really thankful that u gave me an idea. Thank you very much.